# wordpress the_content not showing video

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a separate website and for showing the blogs i am using the worpress.I have used following code to display blogs.It shows the textual contents properly but for video it just shows the player bar and not click able.

I have also checked themes index.php there is no the_excerpt.

When i check preview of the post using wordpress admin it shows the video properly.

can anyone help me resolve this?

here is my code..

```
<?php
global $more;
$posts = get_posts('category=3&numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php $more = 1; ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<span style="color:#1C1644;font-size:1.3em !important;font-weight: bold;">
<?php the_title(); ?> 
</span>   
<div id="lol"><?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<hr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: How exactly do you include the video file?

Comment: Is your jquery properly loading on the page you want to display your video on

Comment: yes it shows properly on wordpress..
http://inforeshatech.globat.com/dev/goodness/blog/
and my custom website page is at,
http://inforeshatech.globat.com/dev/goodness/index.php?pg=videos
which shows only player bar

Comment: i got the problem ..When i add small size videos it shows properly but for large videos it doesn't show..but on word press it shows both large and small videos properly..is there any way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php
global $more;
$posts = get_posts('category=3&numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
   foreach ($posts as $post) : 
   setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
     <?php $more = 1; ?>
     <?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
     <span style="color:#1C1644;font-size:1.3em !important;font-weight: bold;">
        <?php echo the_title(); ?> 
     </span>   
     <div id="lol">
        <?php echo the_content(); ?>
     </div>
     <hr>
     <?php
   endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: `the_content()` already echos, so this line `<?php echo the_content(); ?>` should really just be `<?php the_content(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to embed something into a post or page is to post the URL to it into your content area. Make sure that the URL **is on its own line and not hyper-linked** (clickable when viewing the post).

For example:

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ`

WordPress will automatically turn that into a `YouTube` embed when the post is viewed.

You can also optionally wrap the URL in the `[embed]` shortcode. It will accomplish the same effect, but does not require the URL to be **on its own line**.

It also allows you to set a maximum (but not fixed) `width` and `height`, like so:

`[embed width="123" height="456"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ[/embed]`

If WordPress fails to embed your URL you will get a hyper-link to the URL.

Comment: I have added the video using the "Add media".Also it shows on the preview properly on same page and not a link. It looks like this when are on post edit,
[video width="550" height="540" m4v="http://inforeshatech.globat.com/dev/goodness/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Introduction.m4v"][/video]

Answer (score 0):

Use wp custom fields. Add video_embed custom field your post and add code.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_embed', true); ?>
```

Edit:

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_embed', true)){
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_embed', true);
}
else
{
    the_content();
}
```

Comment: Added custom field called 'video_embed' on post and put above code before showing the_content..same problem.

Comment: Do you added custom field your post ?

Comment: yes..custom field named 'video_embed' and value same on the post